# convert jSon to dictionary

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am posting below jSon to my WCF service, reading and saving the values in database.

```
{
    "business_name": "",
    "fk_loan_id": "",
    "proprietor_details": {
        "office_address": {
            "email_id": "",
            "alternative_mobile_number": "",
            "pincode": "",
            "landline_number": "",
            "city": "",
            "flat_number": "",
            "street": "",
            "locality": "",
            "state": "",
            "mobile_number": ""
        },
        "date_of_incorporation": "",
        "financial_details": {
            "TAN": "",
            "TIN": "",
            "VAT": "",
            "PAN": ""
        },
        "residence_address": {
            "email_id": "",
            "alternative_mobile_number": "",
            "pincode": "",
            "landline_number": "",
            "city": "",
            "flat_number": "",
            "street": "",
            "locality": "",
            "state": "",
            "mobile_number": ""
        },
        "personal_details": {
            "gender": "",
            "date_of_birth": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "middle_name": "",
            "first_name": ""
        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting value of "office_address" as null. Kindly help.

Comment: What code you tries to get `office_address`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var address = JObject.Parse(json)["proprietor_details"]["office_address"];
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: A token based Json parsing

Comment: hi Amit, But i am getting object as value for office_address.How can i do JObject.Parse(json)["proprietor_details"]["office_address"];? Am using below code to convert jSon to dictionary: [Serializable]
public class JsonDictionary : protected JsonDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
        m_entries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var entry in info)
            {
            m_entries.Add(entry.Name, entry.Value);
            }
        }